# Testing the request generated for the backend service

Tags: apigee

I have an apigee proxy that routes request to backend services - which is a standard usecase. In the dev environment the backend is lenient in terms of headers/query params. However this is not the same in the production environment - the backend server operates in strict mode.

I would like to validate the request sent to the backend - probably using JMeter in dev mode so that the proxy does not fail in production. Any ideas on  how to do this?

One of the ways is to copy the request sent to backend on to the response and validate final response in JMeter. This may not work in all cases.

I would like to know vairous ideas that people have tried to test in such a scenario.

Please assume that the dev backend cannot be made strict due to variety of circumstances.

Comment: Are you asking how to exactly reproduce / replay backend requests sent from Apigee?

Comment: I want explore options to assert the request i send to backend. I know the assertion rules, i want assert it against that backend request.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to add an HTTP header indicating that you are in testing mode. Then use RouteRules in the ProxyEndpoint to send the request to a testing endpoint instead of your normal backend if that header was supplied. That testing endpoint could receive and validate your request. You could also do this with an optional service callout before the normal call to the backend.